# apache 400 error

Tags: apache

Today I find 400 error in apache.

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Apache/2.0.63 (Win32) PHP/5.2.10 Server at localhost Port 80
```

I cannot visit my apache in localhost or lan. Do you know how to solve?

Comment: We need more information.  What OS are you running for the web server?

Comment: Apache/2.0.63 (Win32) ;)

Comment: Whithout changing anything to the browser or the server? If so, reboot both, then try again ;-)